# ngrep: how to exclude a match with regex

Tags: bash

Am using `ngrep` command to capture the network traffic(mongodb queries) in bash terminal on CentOS.
I want to exclude a match pattern from capturing with regular expression.

Below basic ngrep is capturing everything on port 27017

```
ngrep -q -Wbyline -dany "^.*$" port 27017
```

But am facing issues while using bash special characters(`!` & `?`) in regex.

FYI added the errors below.

```
[root@development ~]ngrep -q -Wbyline -dany -i "^((?!journal).)*$" port 27017
-bash: !journal: event not found

[root@development ~]# ngrep -q -Wbyline -dany "^((?\!journal).)*$" port 27017
interface: any
filter: ( port 27017 ) and (ip or ip6)
compile failed: unrecognized character after (? or (?-
```

In below command, there is no error but not working.

```
[root@development ~]# ngrep -q -Wbyline -dany -i "^((\?\!journal).)*$" port 27017
interface: any
filter: ( port 27017 ) and (ip or ip6)
match: ^((\?\!journal).)*$
```

How can I capture everything except, queries matching `journal` ?

Comment: put your pattern between single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Try escaping the brackets.

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte its working with single quotes.